# Does the humidified air get filtered in a bypass setup

Tags: humidifier

In a whole-house bypass-humidifier setup, the humidified air still has to go through the furnace filter.

Doesn't that filter out some of the water vapor?  Especially with the expensive filters that filter a lot of things out.

Answer (score 1):

No. water vapor is a gas - it passes right through, same as oxygen and nitrogen (i.e., air)